# Mocking Aggregations In Elastic using mockito

Tags: unit-testing, elasticsearch, junit

I have a method  which maps products from a searchResponse . While mapping I am using Global, Filter and Nested

```
    Global globalAggregation = searchResponse.getAggregations().get(FACETS);
    Filter filterAgg = globalAggregation.getAggregations().get(GENERAL_AGGREGATION);
    Nested agg = filterAgg.getAggregations().get(facetAttribute);
```

I am able to write unit test for the above code using a stub json , that works fine but maintaining it is becoming difficult. Is there a better way to write unit test cases for such scenarios where we can directly mock them .

This is what I have tried .

```
 SearchResponse searchResponse = mock(SearchResponse.class);
   Aggregations aggregations = mock(Aggregations.class);
   Global global= mock(Global.class);
   when(searchResponse.getAggregations().get("facet")).thenReturn(global);
```

The last line does not work , is there a better way to handle it ?

Comment: Can you add the exception or error which you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to mock `searchResponse.getAggregations()` method call. Can you try something like this?

```
when(searchResponse.getAggregations()).thenReturn(aggregations);
when(aggregations.get("facet")).thenReturn(global)
```